# Why rows should be proportional for independence?

Tags: probability, matrices

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have discrete distributions; that $X$ can take the values $1,2,\dots,r$; that $Y$ can take the values $1,2,\dots,s$; and that $$Pr(X=i \text{ and } Y=j)=p_{ij}\text{ for }i=1,2,\dots,r \text{ and }j=1,2,\dots,s.$$Then for $1,2,\dots,r$, let $$Pr(X=i)=\sum_{j=1}^sp_{ij}=p_{i+}.$$Also, for $1,2,\dots,s$, let $$Pr(Y=j)=\sum_{i=1}^rp_{ij}=p_{+j}.$$Therefore, $X$ and $Y$ will be independent if and only if the following relationship is satisfied for all values of $i$ and $j$: $$p_{ij}=p_{i+}p_{+j}.$$It should be noted that $X$ and $Y$ will be independent if and only if for matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix}
>      p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} & \cdots & p_{1s} \\
>      p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} & \cdots & p_{2s} \\
>      \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>      p_{r1} & p_{r2} & p_{r3} & \cdots & p_{rs}   
>      \end{pmatrix},$$ rows are proportional to one another, or equivalently, columns are proportional to one another.

I can't understand why rows(and columns) should be proportional to one another to assure independence.

Comment: My suggestion would be to pick a specific distribution for $X$ (i.e. choose numeric values for $p_{1+}$, $p_{2+}$, etc.).  Then rewrite the matrix $P$ using $p_{ij} = p_{i+} p_{+j}$ with your choice of $p_{i+}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to understand if you look at how the matrix $P$ is formed in the light of the information $p_{ij} = p_i p_j$. 
Suppose the probabilities for values of $X$ and $Y$ are arranged into two column matrices:
$$
P_X = [p_x(1)~~p_x(2)~~p_x(3)~~...~~p_x(r)]^T \\
P_Y = [p_y(1)~~p_y(2)~~p_y(3)~~...~~p_y(s)]^T
$$
Then the matrix $P$ is obtained by:
$$
P = P_X \cdot P_Y^T
$$
Here, $P_X$ is a column vector and $P_Y^T$ is a row vector. This means that $\forall i, j \in \{1, 2, 3, ...r\}$, the $i$th and $j$th rows of $P$ are precisely in the proportion $p_x(i):p_x(j)$. Similarly, $\forall i, j \in\{1, 2, 3, ..., s\}$, the $i$th and $j$th columns of $P$ are in the proportion $p_y(i):p_y(j)$.

Hope this throws some light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For every $1\leqslant i\leqslant r$, let $P_i=(p_{ij})_{1\leqslant j\leqslant s}$ denote the $i$th row. If the condition $p_{ij}=p_{i+}p_{+j}$ holds for every $i$ and $j$, then, for every $1\leqslant a,b\leqslant r$, the rows $P_a$ and $P_b$ are proportional, with
$$
p_{+b}P_a=p_{a+}P_b.
$$
You might want to show that the reverse implication holds as well.